# How to edit title slide style in .RPres R Presentation?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, rpres

I'm having troubles editing the style of the title slide in a .RPres R Presentation.
I'm using a .css file to set the styles, and already tried this:

```
.title-slide{
text-align: center;
background-color: white;
background-size: cover;
color: black;
font-family: 'Montserrat';}
```

But the only I get is a white background on the label of the subtitle, but the slide is still with the default style. I have the following code in the title slide:

```
Title of the presentation
========================================================
class: title-slide
author:
autosize: true
css: prueba1.css

Subtitle of the title slide
```

If anyone can tell me how to delete the title slide instead it also helps.
I'm using R version 3.4.4 on a linux x86_64 virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

I already found how to edit it. The first slide happens to be of type "section", therefore, to edit its style I have to write in the css:

```
.section .reveal .state-background{
background-color: white;
background-size: cover;
}
```

To set the background with the color I want, and:

```
.section .reveal h1, h2{
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

And with that I can have the first slide with the style I want.
The only things I haven't been able to edit are author and date. Does anyone know what is the tag for those?

Comment: To change the properties of author and date, you can use:
`.section .reveal p{ color: brown; }`